# How can I change the alert string based on conditions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

There are times when nicknamesuccess comes out as a string in useSelector and there are times when nicknameError comes out as a string. If either is a string then one is null.

both initial values ​​are null.

What I'm trying to do is render an Alert.alert when either comes in as a string.

how can i fix my code?

this is my code

```
    const Nickname = () => {

      const {
        nicknameError,
        nicknamesuccess,
      } = useSelector((state) => state?.user);

      const createTwoButtonAlert = () =>
      Alert.alert('중복확인',`${nicknameError}` ||`${nicknamesuccess}`, [
        {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed'), style: 'OK'},
      ]);


      return (
        <Container>
          <NicknameContainer>
            <Inputs placeholder="닉네임" value={nick} onChange={onChangeNick} />
          </NicknameContainer>
        </Container>
      );
    };

    export default Nickname;
```

if i use my code it doesn't work it render null or undefiend....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your problem:

```
`${nicknameError ? nicknameError : nicknamesuccess}`
```

If `nicknameError` has a falsy value (fale, null, 0 , '') then the code above (ternary operator) returns `nicknamesuccess` else it returns `nicknameError`

Answer (score 1):

Here template string is not required. You can just use the variables.

```
const createTwoButtonAlert = () =>
      Alert.alert('중복확인', nicknameError || nicknamesuccess, [
        {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed'), style: 'OK'},
      ]);
```